# Cakephp 3 Sum 2 columns of same table

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, sql-function

How to Sum two columns of the same table in CakePhp 3 ?
lets say i want to sum the values of two columns i.e `stitching_amount` and `item_amount` of table `order_details` .. So how can I do this ?

I have tried this piece of code for this but it is not working in Cakephp 3.8 ..

```
$query = $this->OrderDetails->find();
$query
    ->select([
        'val' => $query
            ->newExpr()
            ->add($query->func()->sum(
                new IdentifierExpression('OrderDetails.item_amount')
            ))
            ->add($query->func()->sum(
                new IdentifierExpression('OrderDetails.stitching_amount')
            ))
            ->tieWith('+')
    ])
    ->where(['order_id' => $lastorderid]);
```

Whereas I have done this in corephp and its working perfectly, I want to do this in Cakephp3, like this

```
SELECT
    SUM(stitching_amount+item_amount) AS Total
FROM
    order_details
WHERE
    id=" . $run_orders['id'];
```

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description, please be more specific when describing problems, and explain what _exactly_ happens (errors, the generated SQL, the results, etc), and what _exactly_ you'd expect to happen instead - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$query->select([
    'Total' => $query->func()->sum($query->newExpr('OrderDetails.item_amount + OrderDetails.stitching_amount'))
]);
```